# Why doesn't the following regular expression work in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
regularexpression = r'([-\w]*\w)? ?: ?([-"\#\w\s_]*\w?);'
outputfr = re.findall(regularexpression, inputdata, re.IGNORECASE)
return data
```

It's supposed to catch words, hyphens and other characters, ending in ";". So:

`(hello-nine: hello, six, seven; hello-five: six eight)` would output as [('hello-nine', 'hello, six, seven'), ('hello-five', 'six eight')

If `final-number: "seventy", "sixty", "fifty", forty`  is part of the user input (inputdata), regularexpression doesn't catch it. I'd want it to output as `[('final-number', '"seventy", "sixty", "fifty", "forty")]`

Why is this?

Comment: Could you explain what the regex is supposed to catch please. And provide an *actual* example of `inputdata`, what you *expect* to match and what you actually get.

Comment: I just added more info, sorry.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't handle the commas in your input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regular expression, the second group:

```
([-"\#\w\s_]*\w?)
```

needs to be changed so that it will match commas:

```
([-"\#\w\s_,]*\w?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example inputs -> outputs are not consistent. In the first case, the comma-separated items are kept together but in the second they are separate list elements. Also, do you want to strip parentheses? quote marks? Clarify by giving actual values for `inputdata` and showing what exactly you want to return (including stripping quote marks, parentheses). The `data` variable is never assigned.

Using `.split(";")` might be a better starting point...

```
inputdata = "(hello-nine: hello, six, seven; hello-five: six eight)"
mylist = inputdata.split(";")
# here either use regexp or another split, depending on what you want...
subset = [x.split(":") for x in mylist]
```